# How to determine $A \cap B$ with $A$ and $B$ two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology

We have :

$A = \mathbb{R}^3 \cap \{(x,y,z) : x^2+z^2 = 1 \}$ and

$B = \mathbb{R}^3 \cap \{(x,y,z) : y^2+z^2 = 1 \}$.

I think it's easy, but how we determine $A \cap B$ in this case ?

Comment: What kind of answer do you want? Obviously $A\cap B=\mathbb R^3\cap\{(x,y,z):x^2+z^2=1 \text{ and } y^2+z=1\}$: if this is not sufficient, what would be?

Comment: Make some drawings.

Comment: Yes, it's very easy... My question was ridiculous, sorry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need $x^2+z^2=1$ and $y^2+z^2=1$. This implies that $x=\pm y$.

$A\cap B=\mathbb{R}^3\cap\{(x,\pm x,z):x^2+z^2=1\}$

Comment: Or you can have $x=-y$.

Comment: @jaap You are right